# How do I calculate the expected value of this discrete random variable?

Tags: probability

We have

$P(K=k) = \binom{n}{k}x^k$

for

$k = 0, 1, ..., n$

I know this isn't a valid probability mass function, I didn't bother typing the constant term since it's not necessary. I just need to find the expected value of this random variable. Our teacher said to consider the binomial distribution but since this doesn't seem to be of the same form as that I'm not sure what to do. Thank you.

Comment: why not consider the moment generating function of this random variable?

Comment: The constant is extremely important in calculating the expectation.

Answer (score 0):

After normalization we get $P(K=k)=\frac {\binom {n} {k} x^{k}} {(1+x)^{n}}$. $EK=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} k \frac {\binom {n} {k} x^{k}} {(1+x)^{n}}$. To evaluate this choose $p$ such that $x=\frac  p {1-p}$ which means $p=\frac x {1+x}$. Then we get $EK=  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} k \binom {n} {k} p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k} {(1+x)^{-n}(1-p)^{-n}}$. Since the mean of $B(n,p)$ is $np$ we get  $EK=\frac {np} {(1+x)^{n}(1-p)^{n}}$